# Microsoft Access sql, counting how many times a user chosen value appears, displaying related values

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am creating a query in microsoft access that should count the number of times the instructor ID value, which the user will choose, appears in the Instructor column in the class table, and should display this in the query output.
It should also display the instructorID, InsFirstName and InsSurname values from the Instructor table which correspond to the value entered by the user, as the value appears in both tables.

The code i have so far is:

SELECT COUNT (Instructor)
FROM Instructor, class
WHERE Instructor = [Enter Instructors ID]
GROUP BY Instructor.InstructorID, Instructor.InsFirstName, Instructor.InsSurname;

This however will just display how many times each value in the column appears, rather than just how many times the value the user entered appears. It will also not display the instructorID, InsFirstName and InsSurname values.
Ive included an image of the output here.

[image: fdsdssdfsdfdsdf]

The 2 tables i am using are:
Class table
[image]

And the instructor table

[image]

If any more information or clarification is requested to help with this i will provide it as soon as possible. Thank you in advance to anyone who provides any help.

Comment: Create subquery on Class table only, which returns Instructor and count of ClassID, and then create a join between this subquery and Instructor table by Instructor field and select desired additional columns from Instructor table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems here:

1) If you want a field to appear in the output, you need to include it in the SELECT portion of the SQL statement.  Anything that is not listed there will not appear in your results.  You can also use Count(*) if you want to count the records that match within a grouping.

2) You are querying two tables, Instructor and class, but you haven't specified how the two are joined.  Either add a condition to the WHERE clause to specify how they are related (ie. "and Instructor.InstructorID = class.Instructor.ID"), or use a JOIN statement (ie.  FROM Instructor INNER JOIN class ON Instructor.InstructorID = class.InstructorID)

Try fixing both of those, hope that helps!